# Starred, as to the crew's aid

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, real, cards, anime

*The flavour text (except for the puzzle's name) is not a hint, but a true story*

I didn't really have any ideas for a puzzle, but my everyday life gave me one. I think, the puzzle could be better if I had a better camera resolution, but you guess everything so fast, that I decided to leave it this way.

This is a photo of my brother's cupboard that I made today:

[image]

There is one piece of cardboard, that I covered with a red square here. Can you tell me, who is depicted on that piece?

Hint (as requested by Prince Deepthinker):

> There's a certain anime we're watching. You can probably google it by what's already on the cupboard.

Comment: Can we have a hint?

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker Yes you can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, @Prim3numbah did a fantastic job of recognising the various figures shown on the cards. Using his information, I managed to come up with a different answer.

> Given the hint by the OP, there exists a particular reason for the trichotomy in the picture. Let us first identify the cards in each group 
>  **Top Row:** 
>  The Emperor, Judgement, The High Priestess, Death, The Lovers, Temperance, Wheel of Fortune, The Sun, Khnum, Thoth, Bastet, Set, Atum, Osiris, Kenny G
>  **Left Door:**
>  The World, The Chariot, The Hierophant, The Hermit, The Star 
>  **Right Door:**
>  The Tower, The Moon, Strength, The Devil, The Hanged Man, The Empress, Justice, The Magician, The Fool, Geb, Horus, Anubis (in the top left corner of this door)

> Now, you pretty much need to have watched this particular anime because it is highly unlikely to make the connection between the groups if you haven't. Essentially, the trichotomy is based on a particular point in the storyline, where the featured characters are either **alive**, **dead** or **retired** (basically unable to fight). This particular point is just before the final fight between Jotaro's Group and Dio. 
>  At that point, the only people left who were capable of fighting are listed here with their respective Stands:
>  Dio (The World)
>  Kujo Jotaro (The Star) 
>  Kakyoin (The Hierophant) 
>  Joseph Joestar (The Hermit) 
>  Polnareff (The Chariot) 
>  This clearly coincides with the arrangement on the left side of the door. Similarly, the group at the top represents the characters who are alive but are unable to fight and the right door represents the characters who are dead. (Anubis is a little tricky as it fell to the bottom of the sea but since it's a sword, it's technically still alive)

> So, who's the missing character? Well, going through the list at this [page](https://jojowiki.com/List_of_Stands#Stardust_Crusaders), the only one who's missing is Vanilla Ice! (under the Stand name, Cream). (We can ignore Holly Kujo from that list - she's a minor character and her Stand was never given a name). 
>  Vanilla Ice also fits in on the right side of the door, since he was killed by Polnareff in their battle.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer is

> [image] The musician - Iggy Pop!

This cupboard represents

> JoJo's bizarre adventure. Specifcally, at least the right side, **Stardust Crusaders: Battle in Egypt.**
>  On the cupboard you can see a full(22) set of tarot cards, namely Rider-Waite tarot deck and you also see a *specific* set of 9 egyptian gods. These are all representations of different JoJo charachters. Now since **all** the tarot cards and **all** the egyptian gods that makes up these characters are on the board, this(along with the foto of the perosn on the top right corner) suggests to me whe're looking for a picture of someone (a real-life person related to these charachters somehow.

Now

> I also noticed that the placement of the cards/pictures represent different **episodes**. So just by looking at the bottom right corner and observe the different charachters we can figure out which episode/episodes it's suppose to represent:

> [image]

> These are:  1) "the magician"(the characters name is "magician's red"), 2) the god "Geb", 3) "the fool", 4) ? and 5) the god "Horus".
>  2) and 3) together implies the episode "Iggy the Fool and Geb's N'Doul..." and 5) alone suggests a title with Horus and that leads to the episode "The Gatekeeper of Hell, Petshop...". Notice that magicians red is on both episodes.

Finally

> 4) (red square) The one who comes to the crews *aid*(title) and defeat Pet Shop (Horus) is a dog named **Iggy** hence the person depicted there should be Iggy Pop(The dog was named after Iggy Pop)

**Note**

> I grouped the rest of the egyptian gods in the same way and derived to my answer but I did'nt analyze the left side of the cupboard so much but mostly focused on the right side which seemed to be enough. So it's not impossible I missed some interesting info/relation regarding the left side of the cupboard.

> Also, here's the RWTD and the 9 gods of JoJo:
>  [image]

Comment: The photo in the top right in ones of Kenny G, the saxophonist, who is also a name of a character in the anime.

Comment: @Prim3numbah You are pretty close, however, the relative positions of the cards mean not that much. My brother would explain, but he is quite incosistent with it. However, the trichotomy - left door, right door, upper plank - is rather consistent, and can help you track our progress.